# I want to embed Python to MVC application, by linking dynamically to python

Tags: python, dynamic, linker

I want to embed Python to m vc application, by linking dynamically to Python.

```
    hModPython = AfxLoadLibrary("Python23.dll");

pFnPyRun_SimpleString *pFunction = NULL;
pFnPy_Initialize *pPy_Initialize = NULL;

pFunction = (pFnPyRun_SimpleString *)::GetProcAddress(hModPython, "PyRun_SimpleString");
pPy_Initialize = (pFnPy_Initialize *)::GetProcAddress(hModPython, "Py_Initialize");

try
{
    pPy_Initialize();

    if ( pFunction )
    {
        (*pFunction)("import sys");     // call the code
    }
    else
    {
        AfxMessageBox("unable to access function from python23.dll.", MB_ICONSTOP|MB_OK);
    }
}
catch(...)
{

}
```

And then I want to execute a Python script through my MFC application  -

```
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(file, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

DWORD dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
DWORD dwRead;

char *s = new char[dwSize +1];

ReadFile(hFile, s, dwSize, &dwRead, NULL);

s[dwSize] = '\0';

CString wholefile(s);

wholefile.Remove('\r');
wholefile+="\n";
CloseHandle(hFile);

pFnPy_CompileString *pFPy_CompileString = (pFnPy_CompileString *)::GetProcAddress(hModPython, "Py_CompileString");

CString fl(file);

PyObject* pCodeObject = pFPy_CompileString(wholefile.GetBuffer(0), fl.GetBuffer(0), Py_file_input);

if (pCodeObject != NULL)
{
    pFnPyEval_EvalCode *pFPyEval_EvalCode = (pFnPyEval_EvalCode *)::GetProcAddress(hModPython, "PyEval_EvalCode");

    PyObject* pObject = pFPyEval_EvalCode((PyCodeObject*)pCodeObject, m_Dictionary, m_Dictionary);
}
```

I am facing two problems here , I want to link to Python dynamically and also make my vc application independent of the location on which Python is installed on the users machine. However , I am required to include python.h for my code to compile the following declaration.

PyObject* pCodeObject

Is there a workaround for this ? Or do I have to specify the include for "Python.h" ? Which would mean again the program becomes path dependent.

I tried copying some of the python definitions including  PyObject into a header in my mfc app. Then it complies fine. but Py_CompileString call fails. so finally I am unable to run script from my MFC application by linking to python dynamically.

How can this be done ? Please help. Is there a different approach to linking to python dynamically. Please could you write to me ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is quite triky... I don't understand the problem with Python.h. It is needed only for compiling your program, not for running it. Surely you do not need it to be compile-time-path-independent, do you?

Anyway, you may get rid of the PyObject* definition simply by replacing it with void*, because they are *binary compatible* types. And it looks like you don't care too much about the type safety of your solution.

I'd say that the reason why your Py_CompileString fails may be because you have an error in your script, or something. You should really look into the raised python exception.

Comment: I had tried to use the python header files to be able to compile the above code. for PycodeObject I need compile.h. The moment I include this file it compiles fine but requires me to specify python23.lib in the linker.

Comment: This is because it includes #pragma comment(lib, "python23.lib") or similar. Probably it is better, as you are using a private copy of the headers, just to delete these lines (from pyconfig.h, I think).

Comment: Thanks for your help. removing this #pragma allows me to include the headers and compile my code fine. However compilstring still fails. the script itself has just one command for testing "import sys". For the same script, compilestring works fine when statically linked to python.